# Run hubot as a part of express app

Tags: regex, node.js, azure, hubot, slack-api

I have a pretty standard `express` app, built using the `express-generator`. Now, I would like to automate some of the things in the app with `hubot` and I have managed to successfully perform testing and run `hubot` with `slack` adapter. However, I would like to have the bot be a part of a regular app.

How can I change the structure of the app (I have a pretty standard import of `routes.js` which has all of the routes for the app) to allow for the two to run together?

This is running on `azure` as a `WebApp` and I have set up a continuous integration with `GitHub`, so I pretty much just push code and it gets deployed, I don't run anything manually on the actual server. I would be able to run the `hubot` and server it on a different subdomain or path on the app if it was a regular VPS, but since the `azure` is taking care of those things, I would need the `hubot` somehow baked-in the actual `express` app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to this, in the end I moved to botkit library that provides way easier and integrated way to have both the server and the actual app.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, Hubot has a build-in express web framework that can serve HTTP requests. So theoretically you can integrate hubot with your express webapp thru the router dispatch different urls between express app and hubot.

As references, there is a experimental package project `hubot-express` shows that hubot as a express app startup. you can try to refer to the code https://github.com/hubot-scripts/hubot-express/blob/master/src/hubot-express.coffee to implement the integration.

> The key code: `robot.express = app = express();`

And the article "Automation and Monitoring with Hubot" show the code that how to serving http requests, please move to https://leanpub.com/automation-and-monitoring-with-hubot/read#leanpub-auto-serving-http-requests to review it.

> The key code: `robot.router.post('/hubot/notify/:room', function(req, res) {...});`